# Reindex a select group of nodes

Tags: 7, search

I am maintaining a site that I did not build.  It was discovered that some 300 nodes of type "custom" had incorrect url aliases.  There are a total of 7961 nodes of type "custom" in the site at this moment.

```
$ drush sql-query "SELECT COUNT(nid) FROM node WHERE type LIKE 'custom';"
```

I have found the list of solr drush commands, and I see that `solr-delete-index` is able to remove a specific content type and then `solr-mark-all` could be used to indicate they should all be reindexed.  My question is, **how can I reindex only the 300 bad ones on this live site**.
I do have their nids in a separate csv file already, made from a custom sql query.

Just to be clear:

- the site is live and important it stays that way
- there is only a small portion of the content type that needs reindexed
- I have all the permissions and access, no need to ask if I can get somewhere.  Assume I can.
- I have the means to identify the nodes to reindex and pipe them to various things and languages.  I would even `xargs` a custom drush script if you have a means for doing this to a single node.

Comment: I have used "drush solr-mark-all node:custom_page" and then "drush solr-index" to process all 7961 nodes because it was available with the solr module.  However, I am still interested in a better answer to this question.  I will accept Clive's if there are no better ones this week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't find a better way (doesn't look like there's an existing Drush command), here's a pretty simple solution cobbled together from various functions in the module:

```
$solr = apachesolr_get_solr();
$nids = array(1, 2, 3, 4, ...);
foreach ($nids as $nid) {
  $solr->deleteById(apachesolr_document_id($nid));
  db_update('apachesolr_search_node')
    ->condition('nid', $nid)
    ->fields(array('changed' => REQUEST_TIME, 'status' => 1))
    ->execute();
}
apachesolr_index_set_last_updated(REQUEST_TIME);
```

Untested, use with caution!